# Are permutations diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm working through a proof in my Differential Geometry text book and it uses a permutation (of the basis vectors) to construct a particular function. In order to prove this function is $C^k$, we have to know the permutation is a diffeomorphism. Is this true in general?

Comment: Said permutation $p$ is a linear function, so its derivative $dp$ is constant, so $dp$ is smooth, thus $p$ is smooth.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question but why is the derivative of a linear function constant?

Comment: It's slightly hard to wrap your head around the definitions, but the idea is that if $f$ is linear, then for every $x$ $d_xf = f$, so $df$ is constant.

Comment: So every linear function is a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Every linear bijection is a diffeomorphism*

Comment: All linear maps are smooth. Linear isomorphisms are diffeomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure. A permutation is a bijective linear map which is $\mathcal C^\infty$ (at least for finite dimensional linear spaces) and invertible.

Comment: Could you explain why? I mean intuitively?

Comment: It is easy to prove that the (Fréchet) derivative of a linear map $f$ at each point is $f$ itself. Then using induction enables to get the result.

Comment: Do you have a link to a proof by any chance? I assume the Frechet derivative is just the Jacobian?

Comment: The proof is immediate and based on the equality: $A(x+h)-A(x) =A(h)$ for a linear map.

Comment: What is the best linear approximation to something that is already linear? Itself.